# How to install/use "icheck" and "ncheck" in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, hard-drive, ext4, badblocks

I want to use `icheck` and `ncheck` commands to find files stored on specific HDD blocks ([instruction](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Identify_damaged_files)). I installed the command via

```
sudo apt-get install icheck
```

but this packages is

> A tool for statically checking C interfaces for API and ABI changes.
>   All changes to type declarations that can cause ABI changes should be
>   detected, along with most API changes.

I believe it is a different package. How can I use the `icheck` and `ncheck` commands in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run those checks once you ran `debugfs /dev/sdxy`.

Those are implemented in it.